# GTK+ GLib::Bindings problem

Tags: debian, gtk, gtk3, glib, beagleboneblack

I am trying to get GTK+ development configured on my Beaglebone Black (arm7 Linux) running Debian Jessie and just about have everything compiling correctly (I am cross compiling on Win10 using VisualGDB) except for the Glib::Bindings.

No matter what I try I can not seem to enable the bindings. Is there a flag that I need to set? Or is there a library that I am missing that Glib uses for its bindings? Maybe I am simply not specifying a library?

I am unable to use the pkg-config tool for setting the flags so I just copied the output of `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm-3.0` and inserted them manually into the compiler.

Here is what I have installed:

```
libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a/stable 1:2.24.4-1.1 armhf
libgtkmm-2.4-dbg/stable 1:2.24.4-1.1 armhf
libgtkmm-2.4-dev/stable 1:2.24.4-1.1 armhf
libgtkmm-2.4-doc/stable 1:2.24.4-1.1 all
libgtkmm-3.0-1/stable,now 3.14.0-1 armhf [installed,automatic]
libgtkmm-3.0-dbg/stable 3.14.0-1 armhf
libgtkmm-3.0-dev/stable,now 3.14.0-1 armhf [installed]
libgtkmm-3.0-doc/stable 3.14.0-1 all
libglib-object-introspection-perl/stable 0.025-1 armhf
libglib-perl/stable 3:1.305-2 armhf
libglib2.0-0/jessie-backports,now 2.48.0-1~bpo8+1 armhf [installed]
libglib2.0-0-dbg/jessie-backports,now 2.48.0-1~bpo8+1 armhf [installed]
libglib2.0-0-refdbg/jessie-backports,now 2.48.0-1~bpo8+1 armhf [installed]
libglib2.0-bin/jessie-backports,now 2.48.0-1~bpo8+1 armhf [installed]
libglib2.0-cil/jessie-backports,now 2.12.40-1~bpo8+1 armhf [installed]
libglib2.0-cil-dev/jessie-backports,now 2.12.40-1~bpo8+1 armhf [installed]
libglib2.0-data/jessie-backports,now 2.48.0-1~bpo8+1 all [installed]
libglib2.0-dev/jessie-backports,now 2.48.0-1~bpo8+1 armhf [installed]
libglib2.0-doc/jessie-backports,now 2.48.0-1~bpo8+1 all [installed]
libglib2.0-tests/jessie-backports,now 2.48.0-1~bpo8+1 armhf [installed]
libglib3.0-cil/stable 2.99.3-2 armhf
libglib3.0-cil-dev/stable 2.99.3-2 armhf
libglibmm-2.4-1c2a/stable,now 2.42.0-1 armhf [installed,automatic]
libglibmm-2.4-dbg/stable 2.42.0-1 armhf
libglibmm-2.4-dev/stable,now 2.42.0-1 armhf [installed,automatic]
libglibmm-2.4-doc/stable 2.42.0-1 all
```

Comment: Is the build failing on your Windows cross-development system, or on the BBB?

Comment: @StephenKitt It is failing on windows but I know I have all the current libraries because I sync'd them using VisualGDB's tool. Also there is supposed to be a binding.h file that is nowhere to be found.

Comment: I’m not sure what you might be missing, but I do see that `binding.h` is present in [Debian 9’s `libglibmm-2.4-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/armhf/libglibmm-2.4-dev/filelist) but not in [Debian 8’s](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/armhf/libglibmm-2.4-dev/filelist). You might need to backport that...

Comment: @StephenKitt If you notice the libglib2.0 is from jessie-backports. I am wondering if there is a library or something that is holding back the bindings? Everything else is there.

Comment: @StephenKitt I was able to install the Glib 5.2 library but once I did everything blew up. So apparently there is something that my distro doesn't have. Is there another way to perform binding? All I am looking to do is bind a XML doc to a Struct

Comment: I noticed you’d installed the backports, that’s why I thought backporting `libglibmm` might be an option; as to why that hasn’t been backported, I doubt anything’s holding it back — it’s probably just that nobody’s asked for it. (Backports are done on an “as-needed” basis, if someone interested gets round to it.) You could always try the versions in Stretch directly, downloading manually from [the packages site](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/armhf/libglibmm-2.4-dev) (you should only need `-dev` and the library package itself). Other than that I don’t know...